# How to create plugin for nifi in python language

Tags: python, apache-nifi

Want to know How to create python plugin for NIFI. 
Is there is any library/module/package for nifi just like pysow is for servicenow?

Comment: what do you mean by plugin ? processors ? nifi is open source so ...

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom processor for Apache NiFi, and while it is easiest and all of the official tooling and documentation around doing so expects the processor to be written in Java, you could theoretically write it in any JVM-compatible language (Groovy, Scala, Kotlin, Clojure, JRuby, Jython, etc.). If you write the processor in Jython and compile & build it, you should be able to deploy the NAR containing that bytecode the same as you would with a Java processor.

You can also write a Jython script for the `InvokeScriptedProcessor`, which allows that code to be run directly from NiFi without an external compilation process.

NiFi has an (unofficial but very good) Python client SDK called [NiPyAPI](https://nipyapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).